# Invalid object name when querying a table via ormlite in servicestack

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

SOLVED. Leaving the question here for posterity.

**I have a DTO defined that also maps to a table via ORMLite:**

```
    [Route("/mce/ElevatorAccessLevels/", Verbs = "POST")]
    [Route("/mce/ElevatorAccessLevels/{Id}", Verbs = "PUT, DELETE")]
    public class ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Floor))]
        public int FloorId { get; set; }

        public int AccessLevelKey { get; set; }
    }
```

**Some reason when I select everything in the table using the following statement:**

```
var accessLevelsToFloors = db.Select<ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel>(acc => acc.AccessLevelKey == 1);
```

**I get the following error:**

> Invalid object name 'ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel'

**However, when I put a trace on the db, I see the following (which returns data correctly in sql management studio):**

```
SELECT "Id", "FloorId", "AccessLevelKey" 
FROM "ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel"
WHERE ("AccessLevelKey" = 1)
```

What is going on here? Thanks!

**Here's a callstack**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel'. at
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at 
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() at
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExprConvertToList[T](IDbCommand
>   dbCmd, String sql) at 
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn,
>   Func`2 filter) at

Comment: I build a quick test with MSSQL and the DTO/OrmLite class you had here and ran the query without a problem. My guess is it's specific to your SQL instance/table/connection string rather than OrmLite. One thing you could try (if possible) is recreate the table using OrmLite itself with `db.DropAndCreateTable<ElevatorFloorToAccessLevel>();`. Due to relationships, might need to be done for other tables as well.

Comment: Ok, figured this out. The issue was related to the database connection. I took a second look and the client had messed with the test tables where the table being queried didn't exist. When I executed the orm generated sql statement manually, I ran it on my dev box which had the right structure so I couldn't catch the issue.

Comment: @Layoric - Thanks a lot for your help and trying the quick test!

Comment: np. Glad it's sorted :)